# Terminating a recursive method in java

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a program that is running two recursive methods (the methods add the rows and columns of a 2d array). Both of these methods work as intended however I am unable to get them to run in the same main method body. I believe it's because rowsum never actually terminates and thus colsum never gets a chance to run. How do I fix this?

edit: I would also like to add I get the following error even though the code runs fine. Any explanations?

[image: errors]

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many rows?: ");
    int rows = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many columns?: ");
    int cols = scan.nextInt();
    int[][] array = new int[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    rowsum(array, 0);
    colsum(array, 0);
}

public static int rowsum(int array[][], int column) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[column][i];
    }
    System.out.print("Sum of row " + column + ": " + sum + " | ");
    if (column >= array[0].length) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return rowsum(array, column + 1);
    }
}

public static int colsum(int array[][], int row) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
        sum += array[i][row];
    }
    System.out.print("Sum of column " + row + ": " + sum + " | ");
    if (row >= array.length) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return colsum(array, row + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your methods intend to do reading your code. So please clarify what you mean with "they work as intended", perhaps tell us what you think they "should do". To me,  reading your code, they just make some sum for every natural number there is.

Comment: I stated above that the methods sum the rows and columns of the 2d array.

Comment: These methods don't as intended, or you wouldn't be getting the exception you are showing.

Answer (score 1):

For recursive methods, you need a terminating state. You only have one return which means you will infinitely recurse. To terminate you need a condition (probably involving column) that returns something other than rowsum.

Column is getting infinitely bigger and so there is an array index out of bounds error on array. You should have

```java
if (column >= 5) {
    return;
} else {
    return rowsum(...)
}
```

or something

Comment: can you update the code in the question just so that I can see what it looks like?

Comment: I think you need the -1 so if (column >= array.length - 1) and the same for colsum

Comment: I tried -1 previously and it didn't work. It's only 0 now because I thought that might've been an issue.

Comment: Is the error still the same? or no error?

Comment: without the -1, column will go to 5 and cause an index error before returning 0. What happens when you use the -1?

Comment: I get the same error as when I used 0. Index out of bounds.

Comment: what do you mean by 0?

Comment: I had return 0 in the code before. You said changing it to -1 might fix it so I did. The index out of bounds error is still there when using return -1. Sorry if I was being confusing.

Comment: No not that 0, sorry about that. I meant add -1 to the if(column >= array.length) and say if(column >= array.length - 1) the negative one at the end of the condition.

Comment: OHHHHH, that worked thanks! I'm sorry I understood wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. You can accept the answer so the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a result, your recursive method needs a stop condition. In this case the end condition is the end of the row or column. When it reaches the end of the row of column, it will should the sum of all entries.

I must say that there are much more easier ways to do this. Recursion is not the best way to calculate the sum of a list. A more iterative approach would be in place.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many rows?: ");
    int rows = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many columns?: ");
    int cols = scan.nextInt();
    int[][] array = new int[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
           array[i][j] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        }
    }
    int sumOfRow = calculateSumOfRow(array, 0, 0, 0);//calculate the first row of the matrix
    int sumOfColumn = calculateSumOfColumn(array, 0, 0, 0);//calculate the first column of the matrix
    System.out.println("sum of row: " + sumOfRow);
    System.out.println("sum of col: " + sumOfColumn);
}

public static int calculateSumOfRow(int[][] integers , int rowToCalculate, int columnIndex, int sum) {
    if(columnIndex < integers[rowToCalculate].length) {
        sum += integers[rowToCalculate][columnIndex];
        return calculateSumOfRow(integers, rowToCalculate, ++columnIndex, sum);
    } else {
        return sum;
    }
}

public static int calculateSumOfColumn(int[][] integers , int columnToCalculate, int rowIndex, int sum) {
    if(rowIndex < integers.length) {
        sum += integers[rowIndex][columnToCalculate];
        return calculateSumOfColumn(integers, columnToCalculate, ++rowIndex, sum);
    } else {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought that too. This is for an assignment on recursion however, so I have no choice.

Comment: Then you need to carry the current sum and index into your next iteration and determine when you have reached the end of the row or column in order to return the final sum.